# Can I set variable in flash (AS2) by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript-2

I need to set a variable in flash with a variable that i get by Javascript.
I used getURL method but didn't work.

```
var seguimiento: String;
seguimiento = getURL('javascript:CURSO.recuperarVariables()');
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What does `CURSO.recuperarVariables()` return? Have you verified that the URL you're using works?

Comment: yes, this url returns a string that i need to set in my flash var. Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5207359/989920)?

Comment: `var seguimiento: String;` is not vanilla Javascript. Do you use some framework?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171 - no that's ActionScript 2, as the OP has correctly tagged.

Answer (score 0):

getURl have no return values, you have to use ExternalInterface:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
seguimiento = String(ExternalInterface.call("CURSO.recuperarVariables"));
```